# Handling Text-INPUT REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native

How can i pass my `TextInput` value to the `Translation.get(" Replace TextInput Value")`

```
 handleKeyPress(e) {
  if(e.nativeEvent.key == ' '){
    console.log(e.nativeEvent.key);
      Translation.get(this.state.text).then(translated => {
      console.log(translated);
  });
  }
}

    <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onKeyPress={this._handleKeyPress}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        value={this.state.text}
      />
```

Note : this.state.text can't work for me

Comment: What do you mean this.state.text can't work for you?

Comment: see if i type on textinput "hello" so i want to pass my string "hello" to the  Method //Translation.get(" argu"); so then my input result get translate

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you just have to set the new state :

```
Translation.get(this.state.text).then(translated => {
      this.setState({ text: translated });
});
```